# Trying to enable auditd but svcadm not in solaris 10

Tags: solaris, daemon, auditd

I am new to Solaris.

environment: Solaris 10/ i386

---

Here's my problem:

I want to enable auditd to start generating system auditing log file. (Like `service aduitd start` in CentOS.)

And every guide I found is saying that it can be enabled by `svcadm`.

But there's no `svcadm` in my system; I can't find where to install it (like rpm repos), either.

- no anything like audit in /etc/init.d/

```
# svcs -a |grep audit
disabled       Jun_11   svc:/system/auditd:default
```

```
# svcadm
bash: svcadm: command not found
```

Please help me get the `svcadm` or enable `auditd` in the right way.

Thanks!

Comment: Is `/usr/sbin` in your `$PATH`?  That's where the svcadm command is installed.

Comment: Yes.....I did not even check `/etc/sbin`. Thanks a lot!! I mean, a lot!